# Is it possible to transport units (via Overlord) in the Heart of the Swarm campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

Playing through the Heart of the Swarm campaign, I noticed my overlord options were limited.  Is it possible to use overlords to drop units during the Heart of the Swarm campaign?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the campaign, the Overlords are just basically flying supply depots. Thus you can NOT transport units in them.

Answer (score 3):

I am positive you can not transport using overlords. I did read on a web page that you can, further research has told me that it is impossible.

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Comment: @deutschZuid was made that way by poster.